# python3 install pyqt5 sip ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pyqt5

I am installing PyQt5 using 'python3 configure.py --sip sip-4.19.13' in ubuntu. If I install manually sip4.19.13 then I get the error:

```
Error: /usr/include/python3.6m/sip.h has version 4.19.7 but /usr/bin/sip has version 4.19.13.
```

Instead if I install sip4.19.7, then running 'python3 configure.py --sip sip-4.19.7':

```
 Error: This version of PyQt5 requires sip 4.19.11 or later.
```

What should I do? Any help appreciated

Comment: PyQt's `configure.py` has a `--sip` flag that you can point to a sip directory. Can you have two versions installed and point PyQt to the higher version?

Comment: that's exactly what I didlet me update the question